# No Web Role for Visual Studio 2022 Azure Cloud Service

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, azure-web-roles

I am wondering if I could get some help figuring out what I have done wrong here. I have been trying to learn .NET cloud development through exercises (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/vs-azure-tools-azure-project-create?view=vs-2022), but I have run into many issues while trying to create an Azure Cloud Service app.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling (and restarting pc after of course), I've tried looking up the issue other places, I've tried reading documentation and I just am at a loss.

[image]

Why is there no "ASP.NET Web Role" option when creating the project?

Any advice would be amazing.

I have tried everything I can. I am no expert and I am assuming I just missed something.

Comment: "Azure Cloud Services" are dead, gone, removed, an ex-Azure feature.

Comment: have you tried creating an empty Azure Cloud Service project (without roles), and then adding rules to the project by right-clicking the project?

Comment: The linked article ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/vs-azure-tools-azure-project-create?view=vs-2022 ) is very, very out-of-date - I'l submit a doc-issue because that article shouldn't be around anymore (e.g. see how the screenshots cover .NET Framework 4.5, ew).

Comment: @Dai thank you sincerely for your quick response. Seeing how I clearly am going down the wrong path for Cloud Development, do you have any on-hand resources on starting out with Azure services you'd be willing to share with me? I will continue to look around regardless. I do not have any programming friends, so I am often on my own when researching. Thank you again.

Comment: @AdamShay That depends entirely on what you actually want to build. I appreciate simply "wanting to learn" but what you're doing is like asking how to learn how to build a house by reading the instruction manual for a concrete mixer...

Comment: @Dai I am just simply looking for a way to practice using .NET on the cloud. The documentation and exercises I was following previously were about simple MVC apps.

Comment: @Dai and yea, I realize that I am being very vague. I genuinely appreciate the interaction despite that as learning new technology can be very discouraging at first. I do not fault you for not being able to detail an entire field of development in 500 characters XD

Comment: @AdamShay [There is no "cloud" - it's only someone else's computer](https://imgur.com/GaPPuyT)

Comment: I'd summarize "cloud" development as deploying _only_ stateless HTTP-based applications to [cattle-VMs](http://cloudscaling.com/blog/cloud-computing/the-history-of-pets-vs-cattle/) or management-free PaaS services - while using only widely replicated object/blob storage for persisted data (though RDBMS is here to stay, those are less "cloudy" due to the CAP theorem, in practice it isn't a problem... unless you don't actually know SQL...).

Answer (score 0):

> No Web Role for Visual Studio 2022 Azure Cloud Service

Azure *Cloud Services* were an initial Azure PaaS offering waaaay back around 2010-ish - they've since been killed-off and it isn't possible to create a new *Cloud Service* anymore, and the entire service [will be shut-down in August 2024](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/cloud-services-retirement-announcement/) (it was originally going to be in 2023 but they issued a stay-of-execution).

So it should come as no surprise that the latest version of VS doesn't come with Web Role project templates (though I am surprised that VS2022 still comes with Azure Cloud Service project templates, even if they only offer Worker Roles).

> I am wondering if I could get some help figuring out what I have done wrong here. I have been trying to learn .NET cloud development through exercises (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/vs-azure-tools-azure-project-create?view=vs-2022),

Where you went-wrong was thinking that targeting Azure Cloud Services is a good idea. It isn't. Instead, [you have these options today](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/compute-decision-tree):

- Azure Cloud Services' *Web Roles* was IIS-hosted code deployed to a varying number of VMs that you manage (and update) yourself.

  - Today, you'd use Azure *App Services* (formerly known as *Azure Websites*) though you lose the ability to manage VMs yourself.
  - But if you need to control those VMs directly then today you'd probably use Kubernetes, Docker, or your own ARM (Azure Resource Manager) scripts to manage VMs.
- Azure Cloud Services' *Worker Roles* are replaced by Azure Service Fabric (at the high-end), or just a single VM (at the low-end).

  - Visual Studio has built-in support for publishing *arbitrary* (i.e. not just IIS-based) applications to Azure VMs too.

Or follow MS's decision flowchart:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, you’ve given me a great starting place to figuring out what I actually want to accomplish. This is much more than most would do and it is very much appreciated! Best wishes to you and yours.

Comment: @AdamShay _"This is much more than most would do"_ - I'm guessing you don't know many people who are on-the-spectrum enough to be on StackOverflow all day (I need a life...)

Comment: The life you have is inspiring to me at the very least!